# codigniter database query replace with existing one

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('SUM( COALESCE( purchase_unit_cost, 0 ) * quantity ) AS cost, SUM( COALESCE( sale_unit_price, 0 ) * quantity ) AS sales, SUM( COALESCE( purchase_net_unit_cost, 0 ) * quantity ) AS net_cost, SUM( COALESCE( sale_net_unit_price, 0 )*quantity ) AS net_sales', FALSE);

if($date){
$this->db->where('costing.date', $date);
}
$q = $this->db->get('costing');
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->row();
}
```

I want to replace the above code with with this:

```
select SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.purchase_unit_cost, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS cost, SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.sale_unit_price, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS sales, SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.purchase_net_unit_cost, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS net_cost, SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.sale_net_unit_price, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS net_sales
from  sma_costing
right join sma_sale_items on (sma_sale_items.id=sma_costing.sale_item_id and sma_sale_items.quantity=sma_costing.quantity)
left join sma_sales on sma_sale_items.sale_id=sma_sales.id
where sma_costing.date='$date'
```

have tried in codeigniter but not displaying any results

```
$this->db->select('SUM( COALESCE( purchase_unit_cost, 0 ) * quantity ) AS cost, SUM( COALESCE( sale_unit_price, 0 ) * quantity ) AS sales, SUM( COALESCE( purchase_net_unit_cost, 0 ) * quantity ) AS net_cost, SUM( COALESCE( sale_net_unit_price, 0 )*quantity ) AS net_sales', FALSE);if ($date) {$this->db->where('costing.date', $date);}elseif ($month) {$this->load->helper('date'); $last_day = days_in_month($month, $year); $this->db->where('costing.date >=', $year.'-'.$month.'-01 00:00:00');$this->db->where('costing.date <=', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$last_day.' 23:59:59');} if ($warehouse_id) {
        $this->db->join('sales', 'sales.id=costing.sale_id')
        ->where('sales.warehouse_id', $warehouse_id);
    }$q = $this->db->get('costing'); if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->row();}return false;
```

this is the code where i am adjusting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `$this->db->query()`

```
$this->db->query("SELECT SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.purchase_unit_cost, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS cost, SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.sale_unit_price, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS sales, SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.purchase_net_unit_cost, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS net_cost, SUM( COALESCE( sma_costing.sale_net_unit_price, 0 ) * sma_costing.quantity ) AS net_sales
                FROM  sma_costing
                RIGHT JOIN sma_sale_items on (sma_sale_items.id=sma_costing.sale_item_id AND sma_sale_items.quantity=sma_costing.quantity)
                LEFT JOIN sma_sales on sma_sale_items.sale_id=sma_sales.id
                WHERE sma_costing.date='$date' ");
```

Comment: done.. added starting and ending time of date (Y) thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

You can use query binding by use script like this

```
$this->db->query($query, $bind /* as array */);
```